# Code Analysis- Do not dispose objects multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013, code-analysis

When i analyzed my code from Visual Studio 2013 some warnings appear that "Do not dispose objects multiple times " it also stated that object conn disposed multiple times in object but as i know if i did not use this object multiple times in object than i cant achieve my goals.
so kindly tell me how i can remove this warning ?

here is my code :

```
private void GetData()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            _connString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"];
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from ref_CourseRegistration_Users", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                conn.Close();
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    grdUsers.DataSource = ds;
                    grdUsers.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
```

here is screenshot of my analysis :
[image]

Comment: Here if you are using the using `(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connString))`

Comment: You should also `Dispose` / `using` the SqlCommand as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here if you are using the using statement

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connString))
```

no need to close the connection again
so `conn.Close();` is not required.

It'll automatically dispose the object.

Comment: but why conn.Close(); is not required? if its not good to close the connection after opening it?

Comment: @Wasay - `Close()` and `Dispose()` do the same thing on an `SqlConnection` object, and the `using` statement automatically calls `Dispose()`. See [`Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close.aspx): "**Close** and **Dispose** are functionally equivalent"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Close and Dispose most certainly *dont* do the same thing. Just look at the decompiled source! What does happen is that Dispose will itself call Close.

Comment: @Jamiec - take it up with Microsoft. They say that they're functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

When you are opening a connection in using block, the using block will automatically call the Dispose() method while leaving the using block scope.

So, conn.Close(); is not required in your code.

Comment: Did you mean to say it will automatically call *`close()`*?

Comment: @Jamiec - no, it will automatically call `Dispose`. But on an `SqlConnection` object, both methods are functionally equivalent.